# Tuple of nearest neighbours in a subgraph in neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a subgraph in neo4j with multiple paths, generated via:

```
match p=((n:Actor)-[*1..3]->(m:film)) where n.surname='Craig' and m.name='Minions' and ALL(x in nodes(p)[1..length(p)-1] where labels(x)[0]='Director') return p
```

Now, from this subgraph I want a list of tuples, where each tuple is a pair of connected nodes in the subgraph:

```
node0, node1
node1, node3
node0, node2
node2, node26
```

I tried:

```
match p=((n:Actor)-[*1..3]->(m:film)) 
where n.surname='Craig' and m.name='Minions' and ALL(x in nodes(p)[1..length(p)-1] where labels(x)[0]='Director') 
with nodes(p) as np
match p2=((nn)-[]-()) where nn IN np
return p2
```

but this just returned the nearest neighbour of every single node in p. Including *to* nodes *not* in the subgraph.

**This seems to work**

```
MATCH p=((n:Actor)-[*1..3]->(m:Film)) 
WHERE n.surname='Craig' AND m.name='minions' AND ALL(x in nodes(p)[1..length(p)-1] WHERE labels(x)[0]='Director') 
MATCH p2=(n2)-[r]-(m2)
WHERE n2 IN nodes(p) AND m2 IN nodes(p)
RETURN 
 n2,r,m2
```

However is very slow, any speed up recommendations?

Comment: are you missing a `with p` between your two match clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than take all of the data from the paths and rematch it against the graph you could process the paths for pairs in memory. If you take the nodes from each path and process them two an a time, you can collect them in ordered pairs.

```
...
// for each path grab the nodes 
// and an index for them less the last one
//
with nodes(p) as node_list, range(0, size(nodes(p)) - 2, 1) as idx
//
// put the tuples in ordered pairs
//
unwind idx as i
with node_list[i] as a , node_list[i+1] as b
with 
  case 
    when id(a) < id(b) then [id(a), id(b)]
    else [id(b), id(a)]
  end as tuple
return tuple, count(*)
order by count(*) desc
```